# Textview cursor not visible on becomeFirstResponder : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

So I have a viewController on top of which I add another viewController as a popUp. This popUp has a textview in it, wherein the cursor won't be visible even though I can type and it shows it in the textview. I have already tried changing the tintColor as well as checked all the constraints but it just won't show up. A strange thing does happen when I select all the text the cursor randomly appears. I have tried changing the textview but with no luck, any help is appreciated!

Comment: are u work on simulator..?

Comment: pls, add the snapshot for this situation in your question for clarification.